# UPDATE and then return the entire table post the update

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return the entire table post update, but can't work out the query to use.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (UPDATE ViewAdjustmentsConsolidatedByAttrib 
     SET ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP_DEAL' 
     WHERE ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP-DEAL')
```

Comment: In most databases, you cannot mix `update` and `select`.  You would need to do two separate statements.

Comment: Look into OUTPUT clause for Update Statements.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156604/

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know which DBMS you are using I can give you general answer.

some databases has `RETURNING` or `OUTPUT` syntax which can be mixed with `UPDATE`

Here is the `RETURNING` example from **Oracle DB**

```
UPDATE ViewAdjustmentsConsolidatedByAttrib 
SET ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP_DEAL' 
WHERE ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP-DEAL'
RETURNING  id into v_id
```

or

```
UPDATE ViewAdjustmentsConsolidatedByAttrib 
SET ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP_DEAL' 
WHERE ATTRIBUTION_NAME = 'BASE_FTP-DEAL'
RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO v_tbl
```